# MacOS Catalina left headphone sound problems

Tags: macos, mojave, audio, catalina, headphones

It started after Mojave update, when I plug in my headphones, left one has a bad quality or low sound. Balance is okay and only workaround I found is **go to midi setup -> set left channel to maximum -> go configure speakers and run noise for the left side**. 
Then I get my left side working properly, but this solution works until I plug out headphones.
Is there any other thing that can help to make it stable?

Ps I think it's not hardware problem, cause I got bootcamp working on my mac and It was fine with windows.

MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2017 no touch-bar

Comment: Quick test - may not work - When this happens go to audio/midi, toggle output from 44.1 to 44 [or vice versa] wait 5s, then toggle back. Used to fix me on Sierra [though eventually it was a driver issue & no longer happens]

Comment: I have 44 and 48, but doesn't help

Comment: Was just a wild guess, sorry.

Comment: Maybe any other thought like adjusting some audio config file?